# PHP Array - Retrieve value from Array

Tags: php, arrays, dump

I'm using the following to show my Array contents:

```
var_dump($categories);
```

Contents:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#114 (16) {
    ["term_id"]=> &string(1)  "3"
    ["name"]=>    &string(10) "Recordings"
    ["slug"]=>    &string(9)  "recording"
  }
}
```

My Question is, how do I retrieve the **slug** value?

I had tried **$categories[0]["slug"]** but with no success.

Many thanks for any guidance.

Comment: @brian: comment != answer.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var_dump($categories[0]->slug);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the slug by using:

```
$categories[0]->slug;
```

Because the first element in your array is an object e.g stdClass you have too acces its values like an object.

Answer (score 2):

you would do:

```
$categories[0]->slug
```

More than likley this has come from PDO or something, so you may have multiple categories, (hence the name)

you should loop them to get each category like so:

```
foreach($categores as $category)
{
    echo $category->slug . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $categories[0]->slug;
```

this is object and you have to use something above.

Comment: Thank you Shakti for taking the time to help out. It's perfect.